# Component class instance initialization error [Maximum call stack size exceeded]

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I am using `jsPDF` library in VF page and Lightning component is embedded in VF page.Lightning component version is `43.0`.

`var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');` creates an object when vf page loads and it is passed to `AccountList` component.

At this point, error is thrown `This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Component class instance initialization error [Maximum call stack size exceeded] Failing descriptor: {markup://c:AccountList}`

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false>
 <apex:includeLightning/>
<apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" /> 
<apex:includeScript value="{!
     URLFOR($Resource.jsPDF,'jsPDF-1.3.2/dist/jspdf.debug.js')}"/>
     <apex:form >
 <div id="workorderInput" />
<script>
 var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');


 function loadComponents(){
$Lightning.use("c:AllAccounts", function() {
  $Lightning.createComponent(
                     "c:AccountList",
                     {varpdf:pdf},
                     "workorderInput",
                     function(cmp) {
                     });
});
}
loadComponents();
</script>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```